# Validate unit test logic that runs inside a Promise.resolve

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-native, enzyme

**Setup**

- react : 16.6.0
- react-native : 0.57.4
- jest : 23.6.0
- enzyme : 3.5.0

I have the following logic inside a component

```
onRefresh = () => {
    const { getCustomerAccounts } = this.props
    this.setState({ refreshing: true })
    getCustomerAccounts()
      .then(() => this.setState({ refreshing: false }))
};
```

which I'm trying to test is using `jest` like so

```
  describe('Instance', () => {
    const getCustomerAccountsMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({}))
    const props = {
      getCustomerAccounts: getCustomerAccountsMock,
    }

    const instance = shallow(<Component {...props} />).instance()

    describe('onRefresh', () => {
      it('should call getCustomerAccounts', () => {
        instance.onRefresh()
        expect(getCustomerAccountsMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
        expect(getCustomerAccountsMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(getCustomerAccountsMock.mock.calls[0][0]).toBeUndefined()
      })
    })
  })
```

test runs fine but I'm not able to test what happens when `getCustomerAccounts().then()` runs

Basically I want to test does `this.state.refreshing` get set to `false` when `getCustomerAccounts().then()` runs

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the `Promise` from `onRefresh`:

```
onRefresh = () => {
  const { getCustomerAccounts } = this.props
  this.setState({ refreshing: true })
  return getCustomerAccounts()  // <= return the Promise
    .then(() => this.setState({ refreshing: false }))
};
```

...then you can test it like this:

```
describe('Instance', () => {
  const getCustomerAccountsMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({}))
  const props = {
    getCustomerAccounts: getCustomerAccountsMock,
  }

  const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />)
  const instance = wrapper.instance()

  describe('onRefresh', () => {
    it('should call getCustomerAccounts', async () => {  // <= async test function
      await instance.onRefresh()  // <= await the Promise
      expect(getCustomerAccountsMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect(getCustomerAccountsMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
      expect(getCustomerAccountsMock.mock.calls[0][0]).toBeUndefined()
      expect(wrapper.state('refreshing')).toBe(false);  // Success!
    })
  })
})
```

---

**Details**

Returning the `Promise` lets you `await` it in the test.

Use an `async` test function so you can `await` the returned `Promise`.

Assign the `wrapper` to a variable so you can use it to check the state.